Is it allowed to add a Steam achievement for joining Discord server?
Does Steam allow games to have an achievement for joining the game's or developer's Discord server?

That looks like a sure way to annoy your players.

I see some votes to close this question as "opinion-based" but I think there's a solid basis in fact here: does Steam permit this, or not? Answers can cite relevant evidence such as parts of the Steam terms of service / developer guide / other documentation, or showing examples of games that have or had but then removed such an achievement.

Other games I have played usually include an ingame invite/link, and give you the achievement for clicking the button, while this does cause the issue of you just being able to press the link and not actually join, that seems to be the most common method.

While it doesn't explicitly forbid it, the SteamWorks documentation for implementing achievements says this in the summary text:

Use achievements to reward players for hitting certain milestones or
for interacting with your game in particular ways.

The key difference between what they say & what you propose is they're talking about player's interacting with your game whereas you're talking about player's interacting with your brand / platform(s). My interpretation is that doesn't follow the intention of the rules. That's in the public facing documentation anyway - it's possible there's something more specific behind their sign-in wall.
For what it's worth, you can go the other direction. That is to say, you can pull data from Steam to Discord. The standard terms of use for the Steam API (polling rates, etc) still apply though.

You'd be linking your game's Steam Achievement to an external service that can close at any time and neither you nor Steam have control over.
You should check Steam's latest and current rules on the SteamWorks site ( https://partner.steamgames.com/ ) as Steam can change their rules at any time.

Consensually, game achievements encourage players to try different things, and track in-game milestones and progress. They record the main game progression (quests, campaigns...) or second-order goals (beat the highest difficulty, find secret power-ups...) defined by game designers, to give a game more longevity in the market and engage players for longer.
Joining a Discord server doesn't belong to the core game experience. Also, willingly creating achievements that force certain actions upon players is considered a dark pattern, and players may see this as a deceitful design decision.
Alternatively, consider providing players with optional badges — which they can show off next to their usernames as a vanity item — for being part of a certain community. This may appear as a "friendly" option to get a unique reward while, at the same time, allowing you to promote your Discord server. Unaware players may see such a badge in-game with a description like "Obtained by joining the Discord server." and decide, in turn, to join of their own volition.
